# How to modify the pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```
date_part   spot    datetimes   bad_ticks   gap_count   bet_duration    wins    trend       std trend_old   fakei
1357113602  1357113602  344.25  2013-01-02  1   -9999   60  1   0   -9999   -9999   0
1357113603  1357113602  344.25  2013-01-02  0   -9999   60  1   0   -9999   -9999   1
1357113604  1357113604  348.53  2013-01-02  1   -9999   60  1   0   -9999   -9999   2
```

This is my simple dataframe which I try to modify using

```
und_data['trend'][und_data[und_data['fakei']==0].index]
1357113602    2
und_data['trend'][und_data[und_data['fakei']==0].index]=3
```

This doesn't work. I checked in Wes Mckinsey Book and my method seems to be correct. Not sure why it's not working. Strangely if I type

```
und_data['trend'][und_data[und_data['fakei']==0].index]
```

It gives the output as 3...but doesn't show in the below output. Something too confusing with copies etc? Can anyone explain this intuitively. These simply things seem way convoluted in pandas.

```
und_data.head()

date_part   spot    datetimes   bad_ticks   gap_count   bet_duration    wins    trend       std trend_old   fakei
1357113602  1357113602  344.25  2013-01-02  1   -9999   60  1   0   -9999   -9999   0
1357113603  1357113602  344.25  2013-01-02  0   -9999   60  1   0   -9999   -9999   1
1357113604  1357113604  348.53  2013-01-02  1   -9999   60  1   0   -9999   -9999   2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if I'm copying your data in correctly, but I think you want:

```
und_data.loc[und_data['fakei'] == 0, 'trend'] = 3

und_data.head()
Out[10]: 
                       date_part        spot  datetimes  bad_ticks  gap_count  1357113602 1357113602     344.25  2013-01-02          1      -9999         60   
1357113603 1357113602     344.25  2013-01-02          0      -9999         60   
1357113604 1357113604     348.53  2013-01-02          1      -9999         60   

                       bet_duration  wins  trend  std trend_old  fakei  
1357113602 1357113602             1     0      3          -9999      0  
1357113603 1357113602             1     0  -9999          -9999      1  
1357113604 1357113604             1     0  -9999          -9999      2
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Still this is weird syntax. Why doesn't this work?       und_data.loc[und_data[und_data['fakei']==0].index]['trend']=1. No logical explanation. Funny stuff in pandas???

Comment: @coffeequant because that is what is known as chained assignment which may or may not work, you should use `.loc`, `.iloc` or `.ix` if you want to assign to the indexed object, see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)